# Is it the natural behavior of an Acumatica grid checkbox column to auto-refresh?

Tags: acumatica

I have a grid that contains thousands of records.  That grid contains a check box column, and every time I tick the box, it posts back, causing it to reload and go through the delegate each and every time.  This means that every time you tick a check box on this grid, you have to wait a couple seconds.  This is a problem for users who want to select several records because, they have to wait a couple seconds between every click.  I tried setting CommitChanges="False," and that didn't really help.  Is this the native behavior of the PXCheckBox control?  Is there any way to turn that off?

Answer (score 1):

Below grid declaration of PXGrid I wrote the following:

```
</px:PXGrid>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function checkDOMChange() {
                disableGridCheck();
                setTimeout(checkDOMChange, 100);
            }

            $(function () {
                checkDOMChange();
            });

            function disableGridCheck() {
                $("[icon='GridUncheck']").on("click", function (elem) {
                    $(this).attr("check", "1");
                    $(this).attr("icon", "GridCheck");
                    $($(this).children()[0]).attr("class", "control-icon-img control-GridCheck");
                    return false;
                });
                $("[icon='GridCheck']").on("click", function (elem) {
                    $(this).attr("check", "0");
                    $(this).attr("icon", "GridUncheck");
                    $($(this).children()[0]).attr("class", "control-icon-img control-GridUncheck");
                    return false;
                });
            }
        </script>
```

Comment: explanations about code you can find http://blog.zaletskyy.com/yuriy-zaletskyy-s-blog/how-to-disable-callback-from-checkboxes-in-acumatica

Comment: I don't think this solution actually sets the value of the checkbox though.  It will check and uncheck the box, but when I run my process, it still considers the value that was set previously.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same behaviour. In order to avoid it I had to write javascript which blocked postback.

Comment: please see answer above.